# Rotate figure with package rotating

Tags: floats, rotating

I'm trying to insert a figure into my appendix that is so wide, that I want to rotate by 90°. Therefore I use the packe "rotating" in the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Enrico/lateximages/}}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[h!]
\caption{Membership development of 17 oldest associations that were part of the Zurich gymnastics organization 1871-1911 }
\includegraphics[width=12cm,keepaspectratio]{appendixcommunitymembers}
\centering
    \captionsetup{font={scriptsize}}
    \caption*{Soure: Eidgenössischer Turnverein (1870-1930) and Spühler (1911), own illustration}
\centering
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

However, this doesn't work because when I want to compile the document i get the following error message.

> ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx. See the LaTeX manual
>   or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H  for immediate
>   help. ... l.44 \graphicspath {{C:/Users/Enrico/lateximages/}} The
>   package graphicx has already been loaded with options: [] There has
>   now been an attempt to load it with options [pdftex] Adding the global
>   options: ,pdftex to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.

I know that this is basically the solution but still I can't seem to get it to work. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Drop the `[pdftex]` package option you supplied to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)... It's not needed.

Comment: Thank you. However, I have many, many other figures in the document. I don't need to worry about them?

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about that, since the driver is picked up the compiler, not the images. If you have problems with other images, that means you're using an image format that is not supported by that compiler (for example, using EPS figures inside a document compiled with pdflatex).